# Analytics API Exclusion List

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In the GA Admin panel there are Referral Exclusion List settings. It's very simple and clear.

But i use GA API in my project. All reports via API get all data from GA, ignoring Exclusion List settings. I need to exclude some referral domains from query. Maybe i should try to use filters, but have no clue how to do it with domains.

I'm using standart GA python code like this:

```
api_query = service.data().ga().get(
    ids=TABLE_ID,
    start_date='2012-01-01',
    end_date='2012-01-15',
    metrics='ga:sessions',
    dimensions='ga:source,ga:keyword',
    sort='-ga:sessions,ga:source',
    filters='ga:medium==organic',
    max_results='25')
```

Could not find any useful links about referrals exclusion :(

The question is: Нow can i setup GA referral exclusion list via API?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

filter="ga:hostname==domain.com" works just fine

Comment: This is simply not correct as it solves a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're instead wanting set a filter on the view in the account, you can use the filters object in the management API.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters